# data structure best suited for key value pair evaluation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, associative-array, key-value, key-value-store

I have the pre defined matching as:
Parent ENTITY has SETs of key values associated with it.
Each SET under parent ENTIRY may be defined something like

```
ENTITY A:
    SET A1. {key1=v11 and key2!=v25}
    SET A2. {key1=v12 and key3=v31, v33}
    SET A3. {key1=v15 and key2=v25 and key3=v35}

Entity B:
    SET B1. {key1=v16 and key2=v26}
    SEY B2. {key3!=v39}
    SET B3. {key1!=v11 and key3=v31}
```

I will receive Input as :

```
{
    key1 : [v11,v12,v13],
    key2 : [v23,v24],
    key3 : [v31,v39]
}
```

Which means key1 has 3 values, key2 has 2 values and key3 has only one value.

Then I have to return all the entities which have at least one SET whose all key-value matchings are satisfied by the passed key value pairs.

So for the above mentioned entity A, set A1 and set A2 have their key-value pairs satisfied by input whereas for ENTITY B no set has its key-value pairs satisfied.
So only ENTITY A is the answer.

There can be 200-1000 parent ENTITIES, 20 SETs per parent ENTITY & 200 key-value pairs per SET. Input may contain upto 50 key-value pairs.

I can not query external DB for evaluation. But the Data structure should be serializable to be stored into memcache or redis.

Comment: Please give some details (upper bounds or expected values) about number of entities number of sets in the entity. This may highly impact the optimal approach.

Answer (score 0):

Let me fix the notation and write in python for simplicity.

What you call an ENTITY is a set of dictionaries labeled by 'keys' with lists of objects as values. For simplicity let's assume that values are numbers (but what we truly need is just comparison operation)

```
E1 = { 
    {'k1': [4], 'k2': [20,12]},
    {'k4': [2,20,25], 'k3': [2,3]}
}

E2 = { 
    {'k2': [2,3,4], 'k4': [2], 'k3': [14]},
    {'k3': [1]},
    {'k3': [12,23]}
}
```

Input is just a dictionary, again labeled by 'keys' and with lists of objects as values.

```
INPUT = {'k2': [2], 'k3': [14,12] }
```

I think you should keep arrays of values in sorted order. This should allow you to compare lists for a given key in linear time. In total the complexity for given input should be O(EKL), where E is a number of entities, K is a number of keys and L is the length of the list. Similarly, it will take O(EKL) memory.

I expect that with your bounds comparison in this case will take up to several seconds. If this is not enough then let's think further :)

--

EDIT: You can simply use a set of tuples (entity_id, set_id, key, value), with a balanced BST as an index for values. Then search should take around O(log n). Have you thought about a structure like this?

Comment: I want to implement this in C.
Comparing each key in SET/dictionary with each key in input sequentially will waste some time.
Also after finding keys, comparing each value of a key in sets/dictionaries to each value of the same key received in input will take time. Can we speedup that?

Comment: Well, finding keys will take constant time if you implement it as a Map. Comparing values will take at most linear time O(L). Since we don't know anything more about elements it cannot be improved. You need to check each entity and each set so it gives additional O(EK) factor.

Comment: The only improvement I can think of today is to have a set structure for values instead of lists. This will give O(L) lookup for each key without sorting.

Comment: The second thing is to index SETs by tuples (k1,k2,k3,...). This will give you lookup for sets to consider O(1). It will still be O(EKL) though. But you can certainly add some small optimizations. I suggest to implement something simple, measure where is the bottleneck and then tune this particular part.

Comment: sounds cool.. sure I will start with it & lets see where I face further problems.
Thanks..